# C struct local copy inside a function

Tags: c, struct, copy

I have a struct named "point", and an array of "points", named "A[N]". 
I also have a function, where I want to have a local copy of "A".
How should I do in order to optain a local copy of "A", inside the function?

```
struct point A[N];
int function(struct point *A)
{
   struct point *ALocal;

   ...

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the parameter `A`?

Comment: do you want the copy of the global A or from parameter  ?

Comment: so what's wrong with `struct point Alocal = *A`?

Comment: The name of the array is not `A[N]`. It is just `A`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That gives you a copy of the first `point` in the array. That's nothing like what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit who knows.

Comment: First of all you need to determine if you _actually_ need a copy in the function. If the function won't modify the local copy, it is pointless to make a copy, then you can just use the parameter `A`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Who knows what?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Do we have any evidence that the OP hasn't made that determination before asking how to do it? This question is pretty straightforward and clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this sounds like a beginner's question, and beginners often ask weird questions such as XY problems. BTW I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Copying an array is not weird. And thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry if I my comment was poorly worded, of course copying an array isn't weird, but a the OP may asking the right question for a wrong reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature is not appropriate for making a local copy of an array whose address it receives via its argument.  In order to do that, the function needs to know how many elements the array contains, and the function parameters do not convey that information.  Perhaps, then, you want a signature more like this:

```
int function(struct point *A, size_t N) {
    // ...
```

In that case, your most reliable move is to allocate the local copy dynamically:

```
    struct point *localA = malloc(N * sizeof(*localA));

    if (!localA) {
        // fail, maybe with:
        return -1;
    }
```

Having successfully allocated space, you can make a shallow copy of the array via the `memcpy()` function:

```
    memcpy(localA, A, N * sizeof(*localA));
```

You can then perform whatever operations you want on the local copy, but note that it is a *shallow* copy.  That is, if `struct point` contains any pointers then it is the pointers themselves that will be copied, not the data to which they point.

```
    // do something ...
```

Ultimately, you must be certain that on every code path, the allocated space is freed before the function returns, or that in some way responsibility for freeing it is handed off.

```
    free(localA);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you do not do a "local copy" (I UV anyway because I globally agree with you ;-) )

Comment: Thanks for the UV, @bruno.  This answer most certainly does provide for the obtaining a local copy of the array, however, as the OP asked.  What it does not do is arrange to pass the array by value, but that is only one avenue to the requested result, and one that would require substantial restructuring of the OP's other code.

Comment: why not   sizeof(struct point)   instead of sizeof(*localA)   ?

Comment: Because `sizeof(*localA)` is better style, @DanielC.  It minimizes the possibility of making a mistake in what size you actually need, and it adapts automatically if you later change the type to which the pointer points.  With the declarations given, however, `sizeof(*localA)` will evaluate to the same value as `sizeof(struct point)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-step way to clone an array in C, so you're stuck creating a new one and copying contents:

```
struct point A[N];

int function(struct point *A)
{
   int i = 0;
   struct point ALocal[N];

   memcpy(ALocal, A, sizeof(ALocal));
}
```

Actually, I guess that's one step.

Notice how you again have to know what `N` is. Consider passing it into `function` as a parameter, so that you can make sure it's right for that array.

Also be careful to use `sizeof(ALocal)`, not `sizeof(A)`, because inside the function the name `A` just refers to a pointer, not the array itself, so the resulting `sizeof` it may not be what you expect.

Comment: you suppose the argument is the address of an array and also that array has N elements, you cannot know that (it can also be NULL but that is an other history)

Comment: @bruno Yes, I spoke about `N` in the answer. And the function assumes that the argument `A` points to the array that the OP says it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct  point_A_N
{
      struct point A[N];
};


int function(struct point_A_N an) 
{
    struct point_A_N  z = an;
}
```

structs are passed by value and are assigned by value. So when you assign the struct is copied to another. If you pass struct as a parameter you pass the copy of the whole structure. Same is if you return the structure (or union as well).

Comment: Don't just dump code. Explain your solution and why it's good to use (which, in this case, it is!)